# limit request size on google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

on the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) page it is stated that the request limit is 32Mb and can not be increased

is it possible to decrease this limit

Answer (score 2):

No, but you are free to write you function code to reject a payload of any size you choose.